# How to display search terms on front-end in magento 2

Tags: magento2, frontend, catalogsearch, magento2.3.4

[image: search terms on the front end in magento2]

I want to display search terms on the front end in magento2.3.4 like the above image

Answer (score 0):

**How to Add Search Terms in Magento 2**

```
On the **Admin Panel, Marketing > SEO & Search > Search Terms**.
Click on Add New Search Term button, and set the General Information:
```

In the Search Query field, enter the words for the new search term.
Choose the store view from the dropdown list in the Store field if you support multiple stores.

Provide the Synonym For field if the term is a synonym for another search term. You can fill in other terms, and any search for the synonym is automatically navigated to the page of that search term.

In the Redirect URL field, insert the URL of the needed page to redirect the search results to that page.

Make this search term available as a suggestion for any search with no results, choose Yes in the Display in Suggested Terms field.

Save Search to complete.